# creating decorator out of another decorator (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

After spending several hours on the topic of decorators in python, I still have two issues.

First; if you have decorator without argument, sytntax is like this:

```
@decorator
def bye():
    return "bye"
```

which is just a syntactic sugar and is same as this

```
bye = decorator(bye)
```

but if I have a decorator with argument:

```
@decorator(*args)
def bye():
    return "bye"
```

How does "no-sugar" version looks like? Is the function passed inside as one of the arguments?

```
bye = decorator("argument", bye)
```

Second issue(which is related to the first, yet more practical example);

```
def permission_required(permission):
    def wrap(function):
        @functools.wraps(function)
            def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
                if not current_user.can(permission):
                    abort(403)
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
            return wrapped_function
    return wrap

def admin_required(f):
    return permission_required(Permission.ADMINISTER)(f)
```

Here **permission_required** decorator is passed to a return statement of newly created decorator named **admin_required**. I have no idea how this works. Mainly the return statement where we returning original decorator + the function(in strange syntax). Can someone elaborate on this? - details are extremely welcome

Comment: I find it helpful to think of a decorator-that-takes-args as a decorator _factory_. You pass the factory some args, and it returns a function which is the real decorator, and that real decorator takes the function you're decorating as _its_ sole arg.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When arguments are given in decorator notation,

```
@decorator(a, b, c)
def function(): pass
```

it is syntactic sugar for writing

```
def function(): pass

function = decorator(a, b, c)(function)
```

That is, `decorator` is called with arguments a, b, c, and then *the object it returns* is called with sole argument `function`.

It is easiest to understand how that makes sense when the decorator is a class.  I'm going to use your `permission_required` decorator for a running example.  It could have been written thus:

```
class permission_required:
    def __init__(self, permission):
        self.permission = permission

    def __call__(self, function):
        @functools.wraps(function)
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            if not current_user.can(permission):
                abort(403)
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_func

admin_required = permission_required(Permission.ADMINISTER)
```

When you use the decorator, e.g.

```
@permission_required(Permission.DESTRUCTIVE)
def erase_the_database():
    raise NotImplementedError # TBD: should we even have this?
```

you instantiate the class first, passing `Permission.DESTRUCTIVE` to `__init__`, and then you call the instance as a function with `erase_the_database` as an argument, which invokes the `__call__` method, which constructs the wrapped function and returns it.

Thinking about it this way, `admin_required` should be easier to understand: it's an instance of the `permission_required` class, that hasn't yet been called.  It's basically for shorthand:

```
@admin_required
def add_user(...): ...
```

instead of typing out

```
@permission_required(Permission.ADMINISTER)
def add_user(...): ...
```

Now, the way you had it...

```
def permission_required(permission):
    def wrap(function):
        @functools.wraps(function)
            def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
                if not current_user.can(permission):
                    abort(403)
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
            return wrapped_func
    return wrap
```

is really just another way of writing the same thing.  Returning `wrap` from `permission_required` implicitly creates a *closure object*. It can be called like a function, and when you do it calls `wrap`.  It remembers the value of `permission` passed to `permission_required` so that `wrap` can use it.  That's exactly what the class I showed above does.  (In fact, compiled languages like C++ and Rust often implement closures by desugaring them into class definitions like the one I showed.)

Notice that `wrap` itself does the same thing!  We could expand it out even further...

```
class permission_check_wrapper:
    def __init__(self, function, permission):
        self.function = function
        self.permission = permission
        functools.update_wrapper(self, function)

   def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if not current_user.can(permission):
           abort(403)
        return function(*args, **kwargs)

class permission_required:
    def __init__(self, permission):
        self.permission = permission

    def __call__(self, function):
        return permission_check_wrapper(self.permission, function)
```

Or we could do the entire job with `functools.partial`:

```
def permission_check_wrapper(*args, function, permission, **kwargs):
   if not current_user.can(permission):
       abort(403)
    return function(*args, **kwargs)

def wrap_fn_with_permission_check(function, *, permission):
    return functools.update_wrapper(
        functools.partial(permission_check_wrapper,
                          function=function,
                          permission=permission),
        wrapped=function)

def permission_required(permission):
    return functools.partial(wrap_fn_with_permission_check,
                             permission=permission)
```

The beauty of defining `@decorator(a,b,c) def foo` to desugar to `foo = decorator(a,b,c)(foo)` is that the language doesn't care which of these several implementation techniques you pick.

Answer (score 3):

A decorator with an argument is simply called (with that argument), to produce another decorator.  That decorator is then called with the decorated function as its argument, as usual.  So the translation of:

```
@decorator(*args)
def bye():
    return "bye"
```

would be:

```
bye = decorator(*args)(bye)
```

Or maybe you'd find that clearer as:

```
temp = decorator(*args)
bye = temp(bye)
```

(except that no `temp` variable is actually created, of course.)

In your second issue, `@admin_required` is being defined as a shortcut for `@permission_required(Permission.ADMINISTER)`.